# python pandas Replace a cell according to other cells in the same row (if condition)

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas

I have a DataFrame contains string values and I try to solve this problem with two different ways :

```
A         B               C
student   Poor Family     BMW


df = df.loc[((df['A'] == "student") & (df['B'] == "Poor Family")), 'C'] = 'No BMW'
```

This code didnt work.

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['A'] == 'student':
            if row['B'] == 'Poor Family':
                row['TARGET'] = 'No BMW'
```

this works but it does not change anything at all (I know I should not have used iterrows but i just want to try).

Comment: `df.loc[((df['A'] == "student") & (df['B'] == "Poor Family")), 'C'] = 'No BMW'` only, forget the `df =` at the beginning.

Comment: It works. 
I spent half day for that. 
Thank you.